# How to increase chance of item being randomly generated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on some Python code, just messing around. The purpose of my algorithm is to generate a 256x256 grey square with green mossy bits. The algorithm does not actually generate the pixels, it just compiles a dictionary with 65536 attributes, either "Grey" or "Green, *RGB colour code*". I want to generate a mossy looking slab, and I would like to have clumps of green. Is it possible to increase the chance of having multiple occurrences of the generated value "Green" in a row, either with the Random module ir through another technique?

Comment: [numpy random choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) now has a parameter `p` of per-color (per-entry) probabilities, e.g. `p=[0.50, 0.25, 0.25]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to get random value from the list. Increase the occurrence of `Green` by the amount you want to increase the probability of it's occurrence. For example:

```
>>> import random

>>> color = ['Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue']    
# Here probability of generating:
#      "Green": 50%
#      "Red"  : 25%
#      "Blue" : 25%

# For getting the number from list, do:
>>> random.choice(color)
```

Comment: How would you set it to a variable?

Comment: simply `my_color = random.choice(color)` where `my_color` will be your variable :)